# Where clause stopped working

Tags: php, sql, date, where-clause, clause

I have this code that (without the WHERE, was working) How do I get it to work with the WHERE clause ?

**I just need it to only list lines that is current and max 2 years ahead.**

```
$SQL = "SELECT ";
$SQL .= "SUM(Bookings.Spots) as SUMSPOT, Trips.ID, Bookings.FK_ID, Trips.MaxSpots, ";   
$SQL .= "Trips.Tripnr, Trips.StartDate, Trips.EndDate, Trips.StartLocation, ";
$SQL .= "Trips.DestinationDK, Trips.PricePerSpot "; 
$SQL .= "FROM Trips WHERE Trips.EndDate >= NOW() AND Trips.EndDate < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR) ";
$SQL .= "LEFT JOIN Bookings on Bookings.FK_ID = Trips.ID ";
$SQL .= "GROUP BY Trips.ID, Bookings.FK_ID ORDER BY Trips.StartDate ASC ";
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: do you get any error messages? if yes: look at them, read them, understand them.

Comment: Missing ON clause.

Comment: Invalid GROUP BY.

Comment: Please don't do this. Breaking the sql statements does add very much potential for human error. At a certain complexity you should think about using an object-relation-manager.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Several product specific functions used above...)

Comment: Ive tried to put the WHERE clause in the end of: FROM, JOIN and GROUP. Nothing works. If I remove the where clause it works ok, but I need the where clause to be there somewhere. No errors - Its just won't render with the where clause (I used to have the where clasue before the join and group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `WHERE` clause after the `LEFT JOIN` and before the `GROUP` tag.

You can check the documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) for more answers as to where you can put which keyword.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you ;)